# Можно ли вставить свой атрибут в HTML-тег?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Можно ли вставить свой атрибут в HTML-тег и потом обратиться к нему?

Например, добавляю атрибут group :

```
first <input type="radio" id="qwerty1" group="1" onClick="myclick();"><br>
second <input type="radio" id="qwerty2" group="2" onClick="myclick();"><br>
third <input type="radio" id="qwerty3" group="3" onClick="myclick();"><br>

<script>
function myclick() {
  alert(this.group);
}
</script>
```

Comment: можно. но не нужно. как и onclick.

Comment: @sitev_ru, getAttribute - для получения значения атрибута. По поводу inline-записи, вам уже @Etki сказал, но даже, если и записывать так, то вы думаете, что **this** в вашей функции будет ссылкой на элемент, на котором событие произошло? Попробуйте, ничего не меняя, вывести в функции 

    console.log(this);

И кстати, зачем что-то выдумывать, если уже создан валидный пользовательский атрибут **data-* **?

Comment: Обозвать атрибут как data-group?

Comment: @sitev_ru, да, можно и так. Только "обзываться" атрибут - это не красиво; он же вам ничего плохого не сделал ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Свой" атрибут кинуть можно (*element.setAttribute(name, value)*), но валидацию от любого нормального валидатора кода он с треском провалит. Так же ожидаемы глюки и некорректная работа, особенно в старых браузерах.
Хранение данных именно для конкретного атрибута всегда было занозой в... под ногтями разработчиков.
В HTML пятой редакции помимо решения кучи других столь же насущных проблем был придуман атрибут, который отвечает стандартам и позволяет хранить сколь угодно пользовательских данных (но перебарщивать, всё же, не стоит - моветон это).
"**Data**: Да придёт *(или пришёл :))* спаситель"!
Example:

```
HTML5:
<span data-id='123' data-group-name='Terminators'>Group 123</span>

JS:
var data = document.querySelector('span').dataset;
var idGroup = data.id;
var nameGroup = data.groupName;
```

Код будет совершенно валиден (с соответствующим доктайпом, конечно).

Comment: произвольные атрибуты можно вполне легально объявить с помощью дополнительного xml namespace

Comment: Было бы НЕлегально ставить свои атрибуты, то и `setAttribute()` может и не придумали бы.  
Все ЛегальныЕ аттрибуты зашили бы в свойства ноды.

Но это скорее костыль прошлого, `data-*` сейчас это уже не просто костыль, который выточил из ветки дерева пьяный мастер (нет, нет, не Джеки!), а изящная трость, полированная до блеска перелива теней, из сандалового дерева, со шпагой внутри и выдержанным коньяком в набалдашнике.  
Как-то так :)

Comment: @TheDoctor

> Было бы НЕлегально ставить свои атрибуты, то и setAttribute() может и не придумали бы.

.setAttribute('class', 'ie-hover-fix');

Comment: @Etki, Хм... А как же `element.className = ''` или `element.style.property = ''`?

Comment: @TheDoctor, одно другому не мешает. Есть еще element.classList.

Comment: @dzhioev, это часть HTML5, а тут музицирование по поводу 4 и 5 версий :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно вставить свой атрибут таким образом:

`<input type="radio" data-group="2">`

И обратиться к нему так:

`$('[data-group=2]')...`

Почитай еще про атрибуты data-

Comment: А если будет код:

    <span data-group='2'>I am here!</span>

То как-то нехорошо получится...

Comment: все отлично получится! чего вы боитесь-то?

Answer (score 0):

Для меня лучше всего сработал атрибут `onEvent`, например:

```
<input onYourAttribute="YourAttributeText">
```

По нему браузер напишет, что это неизвестное событие, и он его проигнорирует:

```
Warning: Unknown event handler property `onsetvalue`. It will be ignored.
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).